# What is the difference between "var" and "List" in Dart?

Tags: dart

Is there a noticeable difference between the two?

```
var example = ["some","content",11,45,true];

List example = ["some","content",11,45,true];
```

Answer (score 2):

With `var example` the type (static and runtime) for `example` will be inferred from the assigned value `["some","content",11,45,true]` which will be `List` (or actually `List<dynamic>`)

With `List example` the type will not be inferred but the explicitely provided type `List` (or actually `List<dynamic>` if no generic type is provided) will be used instead.

For `var example = ["some","content","11","45","true"];` the inferred type would be `List<String>`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know and as simple as I can be;
**List** is a data type just like some other built-in types in Dart such as `String`, `int` and `bool`. When you initialize a variable using `List`, the assigned value must be of `List` type. i.e. You cannot do this

```
List example = "sometext";
```

because you're trying to assign a String value to a List variable or object here.
Whereas, **var** is a way to declare a variable without specifying its type. For `var` will accept all kind of data types.

> Is there a noticeable difference between the two?

```
var example = ["some","content",11,45,true];
List example = ["some","content",11,45,true];
```

Both the methods of declaration have same effect **unless** you expect to assign a value to `example` with type(s) other than `List` during it's lifetime. i.e If you're looking to assign an `int` or `double` or `string` or whatever value to `example` in future use the first method else you can use any one of them.